# Is it possible to extend the validity of blue card (Germany) from India

Tags: germany, resident-permit, blue-card, india

Is it possible to extend the validity of the blue card (Germany) from India?

Answer (score 1):

Under normal circumstances you must apply for an extension in person in your local Auslanderbehorde (or relevant Amt in your area).  It is not possible to do this remotely or electronically even inside Germany.

If you are having issues to do this due to the coronavirus restrictions then I would suggest sending your local Amt an email or try to call them so that they can advise you on how to obtain a temporary permit or extension until you are able to return to Germany and apply again in person.

Comment: In Berlin, applications can **only** be made online due to the present situation. So you should check the site responsible for you if this also the case.